# Shortcut to comment selected code in SAS Guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

is there some shortcut to just comment the selected code in SAS Enterprise Guide?

There is Ctrl + / to comment the selected line. But would be really useful to comment just a selected part of the code.

Thanks.

Comment: You are talking about [tag:enterprise-guide]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a Keyboard Macro for this *(Program > Editor Macros > Macro...)*, as shown below. Only limitation is that the selection must be made from left to right / top to bottom. A workaround would be to use instead `Cut selection`, inserting `/*`, `Paste from clipboard` and inserting `*/`. Drawback this time is that you'd lose previous clipboard content.

[image: Edit Keyboard Macro - Comment Selected]

Then, just assign it a keyboard shortcut, like `CTRL-SHIFT-C` for instance.

[EDIT]

While we're at it, here's another one to uncomment the blocks enclosed by `/*` and `*/`:

[image: Edit Keyboard Macro - Uncomment block]

For this one, I assigned the keyboard shortcut `CTRL-SHIFT-D`.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and working in SAS EG 7.1.

Program > Editor Macros >MAcros > Record new

You can either follow the sequence in the right side of the snap or create that using the options provided by SAS in left side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only built-in option in Enterprise Guide's keyboard shortcuts is to do line comments.  You might be able to write a custom macro using Keyboard Macros (in Program -> Editor Macros), but I'm not aware of how that could be done.